# 1D linear equations finding initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading the above topic when u came across the flowing question :-

Given that $u(x, t)=f(x-t)+g(x+t)$, if $u(0,x)=u_0(x)$ and $\partial_t u (0,x)=v_0(x) $, find $f(x) $ and $g(x) $ in terms of $u_0$ and $v_0$.

Now, obviously $u_0(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and $v_0(x)=-f'(x)+g'(x)$. But how do I find f and g from this?

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate the equation for $u_0$ and get a linear system of algebraic equations:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} f' \\ g' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} u_0' \\ v_0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

The solution to this is

$$f'=\frac{u'_0-v_0}{2} \\
g'=\frac{u_0'+v_0}{2}.$$

Integrating that gives

$$f(x)=f(0)+\frac{1}{2} \left ( u_0(x)-u_0(0) \right )  - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^x v_0(y) dy$$

and similar for $g$. So that reduces everything to choosing $f(0)$ and $g(0)$ which I think should be straightforward.

Comment: Oh well, I'm really sorry for the stupid question, I was confusing $u'_0=v_0$

Comment: @AbhishekBakshi Ah yes, it is easy to get confused with that sort of thing in PDE. Still, as you can see here there is some simplification when $u_0'=\pm v_0$. You might think a little bit about why that is (there is some interesting connection between the wave equation and the transport equation through the method of operator factorization).